# C# Web Service and using a variable

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I need to create a project for multiple web services using WCF in c#.  The web services will be calling other assemblies to perform the core processing.  The assemblies will be accessing data from SQL Server.  One of the parameters that will be part of every web service method will include the database to use.  My problem is how to pass the database parameter to assemblies to use.  I can't change all the signatures for all the satellite assemblies to use.  I want to reference some kind of variable that the satellite assembles reference.  Theses same satellite assemblies are used with a Windows Forms app and an ASP.NET app so I would need to have something that all types of applications could use.  Static fields are not good since for one web service call the database could be "X" and for another it would be "Y".  Any ideas?

Comment: Ouch. Anything you do here is going to be a hack at best. I reckon your best bet here is to start refactoring, using a liberal sprinkling of SOA, IoC, maybe a service factory, a bit more decoupling, and throw a few more buzzwords in there. Seriously. And then use some sort of enumeration or neutral identifier for identifying which data repository (database) should be used (as the webservice should be agnostic to who is calling it).

Comment: Or you could just have multiple instances of your webservices, one for each data repository, then the client can just call the appropriate one. This would be trivial as long as your clients apps have the webservice stuff specified declaratively in their config files - if it is hardcoded then you will be screwed :)

Comment: +1 to refactoring and introducing IoC et al. Is there a reason that you "can't change all the signatures"?

Comment: I do agree with refactoring. If that is a not an option, you could use a variation of thwat slugster suggest. Still have a single webservice interface that your clients can use. This interface would include the repository they should connect. Then internally, you could have facades, or other webservices, that have a more definitive connection to the database. Your external webservice main purpose would be then guarantee that the call is valid and route it to the proper facade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that might play nicely with an IoC or DI framework - having some interface that includes the database information, and have it pushed into all the callers for you. Even without IoC, hiding the implementation in an interface sounds like a solid plan.

With your `static` concept; a `[ThreadStatic]` might work but is a little hacky (and you need to be religious about cleaning the data between callers), or another option is to squirrel some information away on the `Principal`, as this is relatively easily configured from both WCF (per-call) and winforms (typically per-process). In either case, be careful about any thread-switching (async, etc). In particular, note that ASP.NET can change threads in the middle of a single page pipeline.